# How to change color in Microsoft.Samples projects

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

Usually in Microsoft Samples projects (XAML) there is a white background color on pages. How can I change it?
Example: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-Communication-Sample-eac73290

Comment: Can you provide an example link? Also it isn't clear where do you want to change the backround in the sample app or on the website...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific answer to your question is that it's controlled by the theme.  Check out App.xaml:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
x:Class="ListViewSimple.App"
RequestedTheme="Light" >
```

Note there is a "Light" theme and a "Dark" theme property for [RequestedTheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme.aspx).

Now if you want to know how to switch from say a white to yellow background for the Light theme (not a recommendation, by the way), you may want to check out [this resource for overriding Metro app resources](http://www.markermetro.com/2012/07/technical/windows-8-overriding-metro-app-resources/).  Be sure that if you do override you're doing so thoughtfully; an overarching theme of the Windows UI design philosophy is a consistent experience for the user.